# Distributed transactions with multiple databases,Spring Data JPA and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data, datasource, spring-data-jpa

Currently in my application I am using spring , JPA repository and mysql database and I want to use two data source connection with two different database.
And I am using Poolman for connection pooling.
Please suggest me how I can create two data source and use for different operation.
Using one data source I want to save data into one database and using second data source save in different database.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself with a simple app first by googling ?

Comment: You will need to setup a Distributed TM and you will need some JTA implementation. Spring supports Atomikos, Bitronix and Narayana - none of them is great and all have some issues. You should always try to avoid JTA in the first place because it is always very tricky to get this right - especially that you obviously have no experience with it. If you decide to give it a go, then try this tutorial first: https://softwarecave.org/2014/03/15/using-jpa-and-jta-with-spring/ and maybe spring boot docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have tried some example using Googling.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

I am also able to get datasources of both the databases but i am not able to pass those reference to our Transactions. so it will connect to respective DB.